# gtk_entry_set_activates_default not doing its magic

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm creating a popup gtkdialogbox that prompts the user for input.
Here's my code:

```
GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("add a new button");
       //adding a new button
       GtkWidget * new_button_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("new button",(GtkWindow *)container,GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,"OK", GTK_RESPONSE_NONE,NULL);
       GtkWidget * content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (new_button_dialog));
       GtkWidget * button_name_label = gtk_label_new ("Press escape at any time to cancel.\ntype in the button name");
       gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (content_area) , button_name_label);
       GtkWidget * button_name_entry = gtk_entry_new();
       gtk_entry_set_activates_default((GtkEntry*)button_name_entry,TRUE);
       gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), button_name_entry);
```

problem is I'm tryign to accept the input when the user presses enter
gtk_entry_set_activates_default
when I press enter(when the entry has focus) I get nothing

thanks

Comment: Have you designated the "OK" button as the dialog's default widget?

Comment: I don't think I've done that, how can I do that?

Comment: `gtk_widget_grab_default(ok_button);`

Comment: unfortunately I have not declared the button as a widget, 
GtkWidget * new_button_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("new button",(GtkWindow *)container,GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,"OK", GTK_RESPONSE_OK,NULL);

what should I use as an argument in this case?

Comment: The button is still a widget even if you didn't create it yourself. Use `gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response(dialog, GTK_RESPONSE_OK)`

Comment: yup that solved it
I'll post my new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my working code:

```
GtkWidget * ok_button = gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response(new_button_dialog, GTK_RESPONSE_OK);
gtk_entry_set_activates_default((GtkEntry*)button_name_entry,TRUE);
gtk_widget_grab_default(ok_button);
```